# Expanding Android Notifications Via Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I've created a series of notifications which seem to be taking up more room than can be displayed in the notification area. I expect to be able to click each notification and see it's entire contents - however for some reason the notifications do not seem to expand when clicked.

SOURCE:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IsXl2ymLkkoTzEqAPpM99tPtKCJgBhAlbWJW2HZ5Zro/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The Android Documentation on [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) covers this pretty well, specifically the section on **Expanded layouts**. The expanded view is done by adding a [`bigContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView) (API 16+):

*A large-format version of contentView, giving the Notification an opportunity to show more detail. The system UI may choose to show this instead of the normal content view at its discretion.*

If you are producing multiple notifications and you are concerned about the amount of room they take up, read up on the section titled **Stack your notifications**.